# QML Showing Animations

Tags: qt, gif, qml

Well for Pictures we have QDeclarativeImageProvider but seems that the class doesn't support animated gifs.

Is there any class that let's us show Animations (GIFs.) in a QML File?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AnimatedImage](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qml-animatedimage.html) seems to use [QMovie](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmovie.html) to do it.